# Button with an asynchronously loaded image as titleView in UINavigationItem

Tags: ios, uibutton, uikit, uinavigationbar, kingfisher

I'm trying to reproduce this kind of navigation bar from the Tinder app:
[image]

So I'm trying to set a button as the titleView of my UINavigationItem, with a title and an image. I'm using the following category to align the title under the image:

```
extension UIButton {

    func centerButtonVertically(padding: CGFloat = 6.0) {
        guard
            let imageViewSize = self.imageView?.frame.size,
            let titleLabelSize = self.titleLabel?.frame.size else {
                return
        }

        let totalHeight = imageViewSize.height + titleLabelSize.height + padding

        self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(
            top: -(totalHeight - imageViewSize.height),
            left: 0.0,
            bottom: 0.0,
            right: -titleLabelSize.width
        )

        self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(
            top: 0.0,
            left: -imageViewSize.width,
            bottom: -(totalHeight - titleLabelSize.height),
            right: 0.0
        )

        self.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(
            top: 0.0,
            left: 0.0,
            bottom: titleLabelSize.height,
            right: 0.0
        )
    }
}
```

And I'm using Kingfisher to download, resize and round the image:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let rounded = RoundCornerImageProcessor(cornerRadius: 15)
    let downsampling = ResizingImageProcessor(referenceSize: CGSize(width: 30.0, height: 30.0), mode: .aspectFit)
    matchAvatarButton.setTitle(self.match.shortName, for: .normal)
    matchAvatarButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    matchAvatarButton.kf.setImage(with: self.match.pictureUrls[0] as Resource, for: .normal, placeholder: nil, options: [.processor(downsampling), .processor(rounded)])
    matchAvatarButton.centerButtonVertically()
    ...
}
```

Note that the button is set as a titleView of my navigation bar in the storyboard, and then I'm modifying the button through its outlet reference in viewDidLoad.

But the result is far from what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

The image remains rectangular and I would like it to be in a circle. And for some weird reason, I don't see the title.

Any idea of what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the result:
[image: Custom Title]

1. Put a UIView in the navigation bar in the storyboard instead of a button.
2. Put the button and the title inside that view. (set button type to custom)
3. Get the NavigationBar Height
4. Use custom init for the `RoundCornerImageProcessor`

Here is the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var centerView: UIView!
        @IBOutlet weak var imageButton: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            // Custom sizes
            let centerViewWidth = 120
            let imageSide = 30

            // Custom init gives a rounded image
            let rounded = RoundCornerImageProcessor(cornerRadius: CGFloat(imageSide/2), targetSize: CGSize(width: imageSide,height: imageSide), roundingCorners: RectCorner(arrayLiteral: .all), backgroundColor: .clear)
            // Downsample to two times the container size to get a better resolution
            let downsampling = ResizingImageProcessor(referenceSize: CGSize(width: imageSide*2, height: imageSide*2), mode: .aspectFit)


            // Setup frame and positions
            let centerViewHeight = Int(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 50)
            centerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: centerViewWidth, height: centerViewHeight)
            imageButton.frame = CGRect(x: centerViewWidth/2-imageSide/2, y: 0, width: imageSide, height: imageSide)
            label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: imageSide, width: centerViewWidth, height: centerViewHeight-imageSide)

            // Quick image download
            let imgUrl = "https://via.placeholder.com/150/771796"
            let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: URL(string: imgUrl)!)
            imageButton.kf.setImage(with: resource, for: .normal, placeholder: nil, options: [.processor(downsampling), .processor(rounded)])

            // Setup title
            label.text = "Custom title!"
            label.textAlignment = .center

        }
    }
```

Comment: Awesome! In terms of layout, it works. But the image in the button doesn't seem to show. Just like in your screenshot, the button image remains all blue. Any idea why @Alban?

Comment: Got it to work by changing the button type from System to Custom in the storyboard. Thanks a lot @Alban